# Trying to install League on first Linux machine, Issue with getting wine packages

Tags: xubuntu, wine, games

I am currently following the guide on r/leagueoflinux on how to install league on my new Xubuntu laptop, and I am having trouble installing the wine package. Following the instructions at wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu for installing wine packages, I get to

```
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

and the terminal gives me

```
Get:1 http://securityubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]  
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Ign:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [83.2 kB]   
Err:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.56.69 443]  
Err:6 https://dl.winehq/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
  Could not connect to dl.winehq:443 (198.105.254.130). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to dl.winehq:443 (104.239.207.44). - connect (113: No route to host)  
Hit:7 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What does this mean? I have already made sure that I am typing the links correctly, otherwise opening the link wouldn't work, unless the links just aren't correct at all.

Comment: The "https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/" doesn't have any packages for 18.04, as of May 14th. This is what "...does not have a Release file" means.

Comment: @mikewhatever I used `sudo apt install wine64` to the packages from Ubuntu and it worked! Now I am having an issue of the league client crashing right after I begin the installation process of choosing where to install and terminal gives me this error: `0053:err:setupapi:do_file_copyW Unsupported style(s) 0x144` on 5 lines

Comment: what command are you using to install? League needs to be installed in WINE.

Comment: @ravery `WINEPREFIX=~/.LoL64 wine ~/Downloads/League\ of\ Legends\ installer\ NA.exe` after following the previous instructions in the guide on https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/comments/5ukgur/a_revised_guide_for_installing_league_of_legends/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has been awhile since I installed on my machine, and the league client and probably the installer has changed since then. That said here is how I did it.

Fist, do the winetricks installations specified by your link. Next, the exe installer didn't work. I extracted the files from the exe file and ran the msi file in WINE.

Note: Currently, the LoL launcher does not run in WINE. You have to run the game client directly.

I have not tested this recently, but an alternative to installing is to copy LoL directory from a windows machine. Paste it into your WINE prefix's c_drive. Remember to create an identical path.

Also see [WINEhq](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=36323) for installation advise.